TransferFrom Reverted on Foundry Test
I'm trying to create a test for TradingPairExchange contract where the liquidity provider provide his liquidity tokens by using transferFrom and transfer the tokens to the contract. The next step would be the TradingPairExchange will mint the liquidity but I'm stuck on transferFrom function
Here is the test code:
contract TradingPairExchangeTest is Test {
    Factory public factory;
    TradingPairExchange public tradingPair;
    address pair;
    ERC20Basic public aaveToken;
    ERC20Basic public daiToken;

    address public DEPLOYER = makeAddr("Deployer");
    address public LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER = makeAddr("LiquidityProvider");
    address public EXCHANGE_DEVELOPER = makeAddr("ExchangeDeveloper");

    uint256 constant MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY = 10 ** 3;

    uint256 amountADesired = 1 ether;
    uint256 amountBDesired = 56 ether;
    uint256 amountAMin = 0.99 ether;
    uint256 amountBMin = 55.44 ether;

    uint256 faultyAmountADesired = 10 ether;
    uint256 faultyAmountBDesired = 56 ether;

    uint256 amountA;
    uint256 amountB;
    uint256 liquidity;

    function setUp() external {
        vm.startPrank(DEPLOYER);
        aaveToken = new ERC20Basic("Aave", "AAVE", 18, DEPLOYER);
        daiToken = new ERC20Basic("Dai", "DAI", 18, DEPLOYER);

        factory = new Factory(DEPLOYER);
        address pairAddress = factory.createPair(address(aaveToken), address(daiToken));
        tradingPair = TradingPairExchange(pairAddress);

        aaveToken.mint(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, 130 ether);
        daiToken.mint(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, 130 ether);

        vm.stopPrank();

        vm.startPrank(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER);
        aaveToken.approve(address(tradingPair), 130 ether);
        daiToken.approve(address(tradingPair), 130 ether);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }

    modifier depositTokens() {
        vm.startPrank(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER);

        /// Error starts here
        aaveToken.transferFrom(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, address(tradingPair), amountADesired);
        daiToken.transferFrom(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, address(tradingPair), amountBDesired);

        tradingPair.mint(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER);

        aaveToken.transferFrom(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, address(tradingPair), 0.25 ether);
        daiToken.transferFrom(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, address(tradingPair), 14 ether);

        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

    function test_It_Should_Remit_Payment_Of_The_Protocol_Fee_Exchange_Developer_Account() public depositTokens {
        vm.prank(DEPLOYER);
        factory.setFeeTo(EXCHANGE_DEVELOPER);

        uint256 exchangeDeveloperBalance = tradingPair.balanceOf(EXCHANGE_DEVELOPER);
        assertEq(exchangeDeveloperBalance, 1);
    }
}


Here is the error
 [19568] TradingPairExchangeTest::test_It_Should_Remit_Payment_Of_The_Protocol_Fee_Exchange_Developer_Account()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(LiquidityProvider: [0x065f134bD621C787D72bC6E620716F9140BF40Db])
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [5137] ERC20Basic::transferFrom(LiquidityProvider: [0x065f134bD621C787D72bC6E620716F9140BF40Db], TradingPairExchange: [0xf1BaDC299848451556aED6a867E56cFc8Ac6288b], 1000000000000000000 [1e18])
    │   └─ ← [Revert] revert: Owner of tokens has not approved sender specified token amount to transfer
    └─ ← [Revert] revert: Owner of tokens has not approved sender specified token amount to transfer

I can see the allowance is already correct and the amount is greater than amountDesired

You do give approvals correctly, but in the depositTokens modifier's code you call startPrank, passing the LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER account again, whereas the approvals were granted for the tradingPair.
The transferFrom won't work, because it assumes that the caller is not the owner, so you can just do aaveToken.transfer(address(tradingPair), amountADesired) and daiToken.transfer(address(tradingPair), amountBDesired) instead.
That should fix the problem:
modifier depositTokens() {
        vm.startPrank(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER);

        /// Error starts here
-        aaveToken.transferFrom(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, address(tradingPair), amountADesired);
-        daiToken.transferFrom(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, address(tradingPair), amountBDesired);
+        aaveToken.transfer(address(tradingPair), amountADesired);
+        daiToken.transfer(address(tradingPair), amountBDesired);

         tradingPair.mint(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER);

-        aaveToken.transferFrom(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, address(tradingPair), 0.25 ether);
-        daiToken.transferFrom(LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER, address(tradingPair), 14 ether);
+        aaveToken.transfer(address(tradingPair), 0.25 ether);
+        daiToken.transfer(address(tradingPair), 14 ether);

        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

